# updating counter index if the value already exists

Tags: python, counter

hey guys i need your help, please don't eat me alive. my python skills are amateurish at best. i have a list of sorted values that i passing to a function.

> id------------**Hrs**
>
> 100000005 **01**
>
> 100000066 **01**
>
> 100000066 **05**
>
> 100000066 **05**
>
> 100002460 **12**
>
> 100002460 **12**
>
> 100002460 **13**
>
> 100004467 **12**
>
> 100004467 **20**
>
> 100071170 **05**
>
> 100071170 **12**
>
> 100071170 **12**
>
> 100071170 **14**

so my code checks an array to see if the id exists in that array, if it doesn't the add the id and the Hrs into the array and increment the counter. But if the id already exists, then check for that id if the Hrs already exist. if the Hrs already exist, then increment the number of times it has been added and if it doesn't, then insert it into the array. At the end, the code will have to print out the Hrs that occur the most for each id.  so final out put should be

> id-----------**Hrs**
>
> 100000005 **01** ( 01-appear once)
>
> 100000066 **05** (05-appear twice)
>
> 100002460 **12** (12-appear twice)
>
> 100004467 **12** (12-appear once)
>
> 100004467 **20** (20-appear once)
>
> 100071170 **12** (12-appear twice)

i have not gotten to the part of the code that handles the final output yet.

my code for this is

```
import sys
import datetime

counter = 0
oldercounter = 0
countarray = []
existarray = []


for line in sys.stdin:
   data = line.strip().split("\t")
   counter += 1
   if len(data) != 2:
      continue
    userid,newHrs = data # data that is  taken from the array


if userid not in existarray: # if the userid doesn't exist in the the exist array,     insert that row of data into the array
    existarray.append(userid)
    existarray.append(newHrs)
    countarray.insert(counter,int(1)) # insert one at that position

if userid in existarray:    # if the id already exits
    if newHrs in existarray:  # check if the newhrs already exist in the array
        countarray.insert(counter,counter +1) # update it number of times i
    else:                     # if new hrs is not in exist array, the add it
         existarray.append(newHrs)
         countarray.insert(counter,int(1))

print  existarray ,"\t",countarray
existarray[:] = []
countarray[:] = []
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do i get to increment the counter should the hrs already exist fo a given id

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

c = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

c[100000005][3] += 1
c[100000066][4] += 1
c[100000066][5] += 1
c[100000066][5] += 1

for key, counter in c.iteritems():
    for hrs, freq in counter.most_common(1):
        print('{0} {1:02d} appears {2} time'.format(key, hrs, freq))
```

yields

```
100000066 05 appears 2 time
100000005 01 appears 1 time
```

Using a `Counter`, you do not need to handle existing keys differently than non-existent keys.

```
c[key] += 1
```

will increment the `Counter` properly in either case.

---

Note: The [`format` string method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) was added in Python 2.6. For older versions of Python, you could use

```
    print('%d %02d appears %d time' % (key, hrs, freq))
```

instead.

Comment: i will try this at once.

Comment: hey man i a very greatful for your help, however when i run the program, i get this error. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'

Comment: The Counter class was added to the `collections` module in Python 2.7. For older versions of Python, you can use the [Counter recipe here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/).

Comment: hey man, i get this error, can not find counter class. given that the code is too long, i put it in pastebin. http://pastebin.com/n0h0rauH

Comment: Python executes statements in the script (generally) from top to bottom. So you must place the `class Counter` code (which defines the `Counter` class) before `countarray = Counter()`.